# iPhone's orientation change back to portrait breaks sites zoom

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios, css

I've a problem with [a website](http://www.cansurmeli.com/other/ems/html_test/application-form-3.html) I'm designing at the moment that when it's orientation changes on an iPhone from portrait to landscape everything scales correctly for the landscape view. But when I go back to portrait, the view is like the below.

[image]

It doesn't scale back as it should; like the initial view.

[image]

I know this is a known issue on WebKit and a possible solution is explained [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug) but it doesn't seems to be working for me since I've the following meta tag set on my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I know there are also some JavaScript solutions but shouldn't the above code suffice? What am I missing here?

P.S. this situation is a little bit better on Chrome for iOS on an iPhone again but then again not very well. Chrome properly scales the site when going back to portrait from landscape but it also keeps an unnecessary width from the landscape view for the portrait view as well the when I get back to portrait on Chrome I can move the site horizontally.

Comment: is the resizing being handled with just CSS? no js?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention. It's all done by CSS at the moment.